# table filter based on drop down list

Tags: laravel, filter, html-table

Currently i have a table that content a drop down list which content the different body part to filter the table. my question is how can filter the table when drop down item is selected?

Also if i want to display the remaining data when the user double click the table element where do i store the remaining data?
drop down list

```
<select>
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select Body Part</option>
  <option value="Chest">Chest</option>
  <option value="Back">Back</option>
</select>
```

Table

```
<tr>
  <th>#</th>
  <th>Exercise name</th>
  <th>Target Muscle</th>
</tr>
@foreach ($exercises as $exercise)
  <tr>
    <td>{{$exercise->id}}</td>
    <td>{{$exercise->name}}</td>
    <td>{{$exercise->bodyPart}}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use JQuery, please try following code:

```
<select id="filter">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select Body Part</option>
  <option value="Chest">Chest</option>
  <option value="Back">Back</option>
</select>

<tr>
  <th>#</th>
  <th>Exercise name</th>
  <th>Target Muscle</th>
</tr>

@foreach ($exercises as $exercise)
<tr class="{{$exercise->bodyPart}} bodyparts">
  <td>{{$exercise->id}}</td>
  <td>{{$exercise->name}}</td>
  <td>{{$exercise->bodyPart}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach

<script language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#filter").change(function(){

      if($(this).val() != ""){
        $(".bodyparts").hide();
        $("." + $(this).val()).show();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: tks alot  i will try it out!